# discord.py commands not excecuting

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I have multiple commands but none of thme seem to work, I had all of them in an on_message event, which I thought to be the prolem so I moved it all into seperate commands. There are no errors.

```
import discord
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from discord.ext import commands
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import requests
import json
import textwrap
import random

yt_api_key = ''

youtube = build("youtube", 'v3', developerKey=yt_api_key)
description = '''blank'''

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', description=description, intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('test')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please remove the API Keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem! I'm going to leave this here for anyone else with the same problem.
All I did was remove the bot variable and made it into the client one.
I think that the two were overlapping eachother.

```
import discord
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from discord.ext import commands
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import requests
import json
import textwrap
import random

yt_api_key = ''

youtube = build("youtube", 'v3', developerKey=yt_api_key)
description = '''blank'''

intents = discord.Intents.default()

#-----------changed this---------------
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
#--------------------------------------


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
#-------------and this----------------
@client.command()
#--------------------------------------
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('test')
```